# selecting correct node from xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi I am trying to call an xsl template called 'Buttons' if i do                     `<xsl:with-param name="list" select="*"/>` i will display both 'save' and 'delete' buttons. is there a way to display only the 'save' button?

**Interface.xsl**

```
 <Cell colspan="1">      
      <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="Buttons">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="*"/> <--this line needs help!
            <xsl:call-template>
```

---

**ButtonList.xsl**

```
<xsl:template name="Buttons">
        <xsl:param name="list"/>

    <ButtonList>
        <xsl:for-each select="$list/*">                 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Action='SAVE'">
                     //code for style of button
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Action='DELETE'">
                     //code for style of button
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>                 
     </ButtonList>
<xsl:template>
```

---

input xml

```
<StaticLabelList>
            <StaticLabel style="font-family:Arial;color:#1370df;font-size:10pt">
                <Name><![CDATA[SECTION_TITLE]]></Name>
                <Caption><![CDATA[Buttons]]></Caption>
            </StaticLabel>
        </StaticLabelList>
        <ButtonList>
            <Button style="font-family:Arial Narrow;color:#E6E7E8;font-size:10pt;background-color:#94c1f6;text-decoration:none">
                <Label><![CDATA[SAVE]]></Label>
                <Url><![CDATA[#]]></Url>
                <Onclick><![CDATA[submitForm('/Controller/SEND','theForm'); return (false);]]></Onclick>
                <Action><![CDATA[SAVE]]></Action>
                <ReadOnly rtexprvalue="true"><![CDATA[mb.isReadonlyButton("N",2,2)]]></ReadOnly>
            </Button>
            <Button style="font-family:Arial Narrow;color:#E6E7E8;font-size:10pt;background-color:#94c1f6;text-decoration:none">
                <Label><![CDATA[DELETE]]></Label>
                <Url><![CDATA[#]]></Url>
                <Onclick><![CDATA[submitForm('/Controller/DELETE','theForm'); return (false);]]></Onclick>
                <Action><![CDATA[PREV]]></Action>
                <ReadOnly rtexprvalue="true"><![CDATA[mb.isReadonlyButton("Y",2,2)]]></ReadOnly>
            </Button>
```

Comment: What does the input XML look like?

Comment: @IanRoberts uploaded input xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<xsl:for-each select="$list/*">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$list/*[Action = 'SAVE']">
```

Then, only SAVE items are selected from the parameter.

**Alternative solution**

Change

```
<xsl:call-template name="Buttons">
   <xsl:with-param name="list" select="*"/> <--this line needs help!
<xsl:call-template>
```

To

```
<xsl:call-template name="Buttons">
   <xsl:with-param name="list" select="*[Action = 'SAVE']"/> <--this line needs help!
<xsl:call-template>
```

Then, only SAVE items end up being handed to the called template in the first place.

Comment: i need to change the line `<xsl:with-param name="list" select="*"/>` in the first part of the question

Comment: @bouncingHippo How do you know you need to change one particular line in your code? Edited my answer.

Comment: oops i forgot to update `ButtonList.xsl`. can you take a look at it again?

Comment: @bouncingHippo I do not see any changes. How about you try my suggestions first?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "somehow it doesn't work"? Or else, post your complete XSLT code and complete XML samples.

Comment: silly mistake by me, it works i really like your solution, its nice and clean!